# Rename custom post type list page default action buttons WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How to rename the particular custom post type list page action buttons in WordPress?

Is there any hook to rename the action button of particular custom post type?

Comment: please give what you have tried?

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is the code you need to add into your theme functions file.
// Replace Posts label as Articles in Admin Panel 

function change_post_menu_label() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'Articles';
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Articles';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add Articles';
    echo '';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_post_menu_label' );
```